# How to prove an average inequality about limsup\liminf

Tags: analysis, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $an$ is an infinite sequence in $\Bbb R$ and $bn$ is the arithmetic average of $an$, or $bk = \frac{(a_1 + ... + a_k)}k$

Why is it true that:
$\lim$(inf $an) \le$ $\lim$(inf $bn) \le \lim$(sup $bn) \le \lim$(sup $an$)

Comment: Can you prove any of the inequalities (say, at least, the middle one?)

Comment: Thanks for the editing from abc... (can't see your name after I added two more parenthesis) of the formula.

Comment: @Michael, middle one follows that inf(A) <= sup(A), and inequality of limit

Comment: I don't know what $\inf(A)$ means in this context.

Comment: @Michael, for any bounded non-empty subset of R, A, we have inf(A) <= sup(A).

Comment: $\inf (A)$ for a set $A$ is not the same as $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n$, and so your explanation of the middle case is lacking.

Comment: @Michael, there's a second part of my explanation comment that I need to use the inequality of limit.

Comment: I do not know what what you mean, or what "inequality of limit" means in this context, or what the set $A$ is supposed to be.  The problem is not hard and so it may help to be precise about the parts you can do...it may lead to also being able to do the other parts.

Comment: @Michael, for the middle inequality, inf({bk|k>=n}) <= sup({bk|k>=n}), for any n, since for any subset A in R, inf(A) <= sup(A); and, if for two sequences (an), (bn), an <= bn for all n, and they both converge, then lim (an) <= lim (bn). Combine these two, lim (inf(bn)) <= lim (sup(bn)). sorry for any misleading.

Comment: That looks good.  The right-most inequality looks like it can follow by the fact that, if we define $\alpha = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $a_n \leq \alpha + \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of notation let $$
\ell_n = \inf_{n\leq m < \infty}a_m
$$

For the first inequality use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\inf$: For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N$ (possibly depending on $n$) so that $\ell_n < a_m+\epsilon $ for all $m > N$, hence

\begin{align}
\ell_n = \frac{(m-N)\ell_n}{m-N}
%
&< \frac{(a_{N+1}+\epsilon)+\dotsb+ (a_m+\epsilon) }{m-N}\\
%
&= \frac{a_{N+1}+\dotsb+ a_m}{m}\cdot \frac{m}{m-N} + \epsilon\\
%
&= \left(b_n - \frac{a_1+\dotsb+ a_N}{m}\right) \cdot \frac{m}{m-N} + \epsilon
\end{align}

Given that it holds for all $m > N$,

\begin{align}
\ell_n
&\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\bigg(b_n - \underbrace{(a_{1}+\dotsb+ a_N)}_{\text{constant in $m$}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{m}}_{\to\,0}\bigg)\cdot \underbrace{\frac{m}{m-N}}_{\to\,1} + \epsilon
= b_n+\epsilon
\end{align}

This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, so let $\epsilon \to 0^+$, giving
$\ell_n \leq b_n$. The first inequality follows:

\begin{align}\operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty}a_n
&= \operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty}\inf_{n\leq m < \infty}a_m
%
= \operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty} \ell_n\\
%
&\leq \operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty} b_n
\end{align}

For the second inequality, trivially
$$\operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty} b_n \leq \operatorname{lim\,sup}_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

And finally, for the third inequality consider $(-a_n)$ and $(-b_n)$. Applying the first inequality to these (noting that the arithmetic mean of negation is the negation of the arithmetic mean) we have
$$\operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty} (-a_n)
\leq \operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty} (-b_n)$$
and given that $\operatorname{lim\,sup}_{n\to\infty}(-x_n) = -\operatorname{lim\,inf}_{n\to\infty}x_n$
we conclude

$$-\operatorname{lim\,sup}_{n\to\infty}a_n
\leq -\operatorname{lim\,sup}_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

Comment: something a little bit strange... l(n) < (b(n) - ...) * m / (m - N) + eps, the b(n) should be b(m)?